# How can I return the HTML block from inside of my map function?

Tags: javascript

How can I return the HTML block from inside of my map function?

Here is my code:

```js
const userList = document.querySelector('#userList');

userList.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  function renderUsers(doc) {
    doc.map((doci) => {
      ('<h1>' + doci.data().firstName + '</h1>')
    })
  }

  // get user info from firestore
  db.collection('users').get().then((users) => {
    return renderUsers(users.docs)
  })
})
```

Comment: It seems to me that you are mixing up server-side (db.collection('users')) and client-side (document.querySelector('#userList')) code.

Comment: You need to return from `map` callback: `return ('<h1>'..` and from `renderUsers` function:  `return doc.map(...)`. You don't need to return from the `then` callback. `userList.innerHTML = renderUsers(users.docs).join("")`

Comment: I think @DanielApostolov is right. I don't believe you can do `db.collection('users')` from a browser. You never access a database directly from a browser. Imagine if it was possible, anybody could mess up with your data, erase your database etc.

Answer (score 0):

`map` returns an array. So in you case if you need to get an array of `h1` tags try below code

```
    var h1Array = doc.map((doci) => {
                     return  '<h1>' + doci.data().firstName + '</h1>'
                  })
```

if you dont want to use the `return` keyword you can use like this. I am not sure what `data()` does though.

```
doc.map((doci) => ('<h1>' + doci.data().firstName + '</h1>'))
```

`h1Array` will be an array like below.

```
['<h1>xxx</h1>', '<h1>xxx1</h1>', '<h1>xxx2</h1>' ]
```